# Is there a point that lies on the boundary of the unit ball in $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$, and close to the zero-sequence in $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am an engineer who is brushing up some functional analysis. I am curious about the following problem I posed to myself:

Consider the sequence space of real-valued sequences that will eventually become $0$, i.e. $$c_{00}(\mathbb{R})=\{(x_n)_n:\mbox{ there is a }k\in\mathbb{N} \mbox{such that }x_m=0 \mbox{ for all m>k}\}.$$

Consider the normed spaces $X_1=(c_{00}(\mathbb{R}),\lVert\cdot\rVert_1)$ and $X_2=(c_{00}(\mathbb{R}),\lVert\cdot\rVert_2)$, where $\lVert\cdot\rVert_1$ and $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ are the usual [$\ell_p$ - norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_space#.E2.84.93p_spaces).

Let $B_1$ denote the closed unit ball in $X_1$.

Is there a point $p\in X_1$ such that $p$ lies on the boundary of $B_1$, but is closer to the zero-sequence $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ with respect to $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$?

Comment: Closer than what?

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want $p$ such that $\lVert p \rVert_1=1$ and $\lVert p \rVert_2<1$?

Answer (score 1):

You want sequences very close to zero  in the $l_2$ norm but with $l_1$ norm $1$. The freedom that $c_{00}$ offers is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with no restriction on $n$.

Consider the element

$$p_n=(\frac{1}{n}, \ldots, \frac{1}{n}, 0,0,\ldots)$$
with $n$ components equal to $\frac{1}{n}$ and the rest zero. We have $||p_n||_1=1$ and
$||p_n||_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$, and for  $n$ large this can be arbitrarily small.

Similarly you can do $||\cdot ||_p$ and $||\cdot ||_q$ where $p<q$, instead of $||\cdot ||_1$ and $||\cdot ||_2$.